# How to fix "One or more validation errors were detected during model generation"-error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

**SportsStore.Domain.Concrete.shop_Products: : EntityType 'shop_Products' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.**

**Products: EntityType: EntitySet 'Products' is based on type 'shop_Products' that has no keys defined.**

```
 public ViewResult Index()
    {

        ProductsListViewModel viewModel = new ProductsListViewModel
        {
            Products = repository.Products
                .Where(p => p.CategoryId == 100)
                .OrderByDescending(p=>p.ProductID)
                .Take(5)
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }


@foreach (var p in Model.Products)
{

<a href="">@p.ProductName</a>
}


public class shop_Products {
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CategoryPropertyId { get; set; }
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProductBrandId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> MarketPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> UserPrice { get; set; }
    public string TitleKeyword { get; set; }
    public string MetaKeyword { get; set; }
    public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
    public string PhotoName { get; set; }
    public string PhotoPath { get; set; }
    public string smallPhotos { get; set; }
    public string BigPhotos { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public double Discount { get; set; }
    public int Inventory { get; set; }
    public string ShortDesc { get; set; }
    public bool IsAccessories { get; set; }
    public bool IsGroup { get; set; }
    public bool IsTopService { get; set; }
    public string Accessorices { get; set; }
    public string PeopleGroup { get; set; }
    public string TopService { get; set; }
    public string Contents { get; set; }
    public string Parameter { get; set; }
    public string PackingList { get; set; }
    public string Service { get; set; }
    public string Professional { get; set; }
    public bool IsParameter { get; set; }
    public bool IsPackingList { get; set; }
    public bool IsService { get; set; }
    public bool IsProfessional { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsEnable { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsCommend { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsTop { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsBest { get; set; }
    public string ProductBrandType { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Makein { get; set; }
    public string weight { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime InputTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Sort { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SeeCount { get; set; }
}
```

I made a few of these,and works well.But these is wrong.Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 18):

By convention EF uses either the field `Id` or `[type name]Id` as a Primary Key. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.idkeydiscoveryconvention%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

The fact that your  type is named `shop_Products` but you have the key set to `ProductID` (assumption) means it cant find one by convention. So you can either change the field name or type name or add the data annotation `[Key]` above `ProductID` like so:

```
[Key]
public int ProductID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 10):

Add this namespace ref `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` to your model and then add the `[Key]` annotation above your id property

Answer (score 4):

namespace: using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

```
[Key] public int ProductID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also just rename productID to id

```
public int id {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code for this type of problem in asp.net mvc

before

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace glostars.Models
{
    public class WeeklyTagged
    {
        public int TaggedId { get; set; }          
    }
}
```

after

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;  //added this line
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace glostars.Models
{
    public class WeeklyTagged
    {
        [Key]                                   //and this line
        public int TaggedId { get; set; }          
    }
}
```

And now it works. Thank you

Comment: Three of four existing answers already state this. What's the added value of your answer?

Comment: There are so many beginner developer like me . I think if anyone answered like me its more helpful for them. That's why I answered like a beginner way.

Comment: Which beginner won't understand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23071573/861716)?

Comment: Best example that is me :D